# Envio de string por Node pela porta serial ao Arduino

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial

Tenho um servidor local que fica escutando o terminal serial do Arduino e a partir de certos dados, ele é capaz de fazer um *select* em um banco de dados MySQL para saber se uma tag RFID é cadastrada (e portanto está com acesso liberado). Se a consulta retorna algum resultado, então essa tag está realmente cadastrada e a partir daí envia um string para o terminal serial a fim do Arduino ler essa string e realizar algumas ações.

O problema é que a leitura da string pelo Arduino só é feita na próxima vez que uma tag RFID é escaneada. Vejam a imagem abaixo para entender melhor: observando a mensagem `Status do cartão - Node: #` (é apenas um console.log, onde o # simboliza a string que será enviada ao Arduino, uma variável), vejam que logo abaixo dela aparece a mensagem `Mensagem: Acesso negado!`, mas nas próximas vezes abaixo de `Status do cartão` aparece *true* *ou false*, nesse caso já são as strings que o Arduino está realmente lendo.

[image: Console Bash]

O que acontece: eu escaneei 2 vezes uma tag cadastrada e 1 vez uma tag sem cadastro. No caso, recebi acesso negado na primeira vez (quando deveria ser liberado), no segundo escanamento eu recebo o acesso liberado por conta da primeiro scan e no último escanamento onde o `status` do cartão é *false*, o Arduino leu *true* por ter passado um cartão liberado antes. Ou seja, os comandos enviados pelo Node estão sendo lidos apenas no próximo scan feito pelo sensor RFID.

Esse é o código do Arduino:

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#define PORTA_AN 0
#define PORTA_DIG 3
#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9

// Definicoes pino modulo RC522
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);

//Porta do buzzer
int buzzer = 4;

//Leds indicadores de acesso: liberado ou negado
int led_liberado = 7;
int led_negado = 6;

//Condição de acesso
bool condicao = false;

char st[20];

//Portas do relê usado para abrir e fechar o portão
int portaRele = 2;
int portaRele2 = 8;

void setup()
{
    //Setagem dos acessórios conectados
    pinMode(portaRele, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(portaRele, HIGH);
    pinMode(portaRele2, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(portaRele2, HIGH);
    pinMode(led_liberado, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led_negado, OUTPUT);

    //Inicia a serial
    Serial.begin(9600); 

    //Inicia  SPI bus
    SPI.begin();

    //Inicia MFRC522
    mfrc522.PCD_Init();

    //Buzzer
    pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
    delay(150);
    digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);

    //Mensagens iniciais no serial monitor
    Serial.println("Aproxime o seu cartão do leitor...");
    Serial.println();
}

void LeRFID()
{
    //Aguarda a aproximacao do cartao
    if (!mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
    {
        return;
    }

    //Seleciona um dos cartoes
    if (!mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
    {
        return;
    }

    //Mostra UID na serial
    Serial.println("UID da tag:");
    String conteudo = "";
    byte letra;
    for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++)
    {
        Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : "");
        Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
    }

  //Lê o input enviado pelo Node 
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String input = Serial.readString();
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println(input);  
    if (input == "true")
    {
      condicao = true;
      input = "";
    }
    else
    {
      condicao = false;
      input = "";
    }
  } 

    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Mensagem: "); 

    //Abre o portão e acende o led verde
    if (condicao == true)
    {
        Serial.println("Acesso liberado!");
        Serial.println();
        digitalWrite(led_liberado, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
        delay(150);
        digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
        delay(1000);        
        digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
        delay(150);
        digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
        delay(1000);
        digitalWrite(led_liberado, LOW);
        digitalWrite(portaRele, LOW);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(portaRele, HIGH);
        delay(3000);
        digitalWrite(portaRele2, LOW);
        delay(400);
        digitalWrite(portaRele2, HIGH);
    }
    else //Nega acesso e pisca o led vermelho
    {
        Serial.println("Acesso negado!");
        Serial.println();               
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
        {
            digitalWrite(led_negado, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);
            delay(100);
            digitalWrite(led_negado, LOW);
            digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
            delay(100);
        }
    }  
}

void loop()
{
    LeRFID();
    delay(500);
}
```

O código da aplicação em Node:

```js
const MySQL = require('mysql');

const con = MySQL.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: "3306",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "Arduino",
    charset: "utf8mb4_general_ci"
});

con.connect((err) => {
    if (err)
        console.error(err);
    console.log("Conectado ao banco de dados");
});

var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(4000, () => { //Inicia o servidor express na porta 4000
    console.log('Servidor Express iniciado na porta %s', server.address().port);
})

var io = require('socket.io')(server); //Vincula socket.io com o servidor express

app.use(express.static('public'));

// Conexão com o Arduino
const SerialPort = require('serialport'); 
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const port = new SerialPort('COM3',{ baudRate: 9600 }); //Conecta o serial port à porta COM3
const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({delimiter: '\r\n'})); //Lê a linha quando uma nova linha chega
parser.on('data', (message) => { //Lê os dados    
    console.log(message);

    if (message.length == 8 || message.length == 9) //Compara se a string é do mesmo tamanho da tag que o serial imprime
        InsertRFIDHistorico(message);    
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("Alguém se conectou.");
})

var cartaoSalvo;
function InsertRFIDHistorico(value) {  
    const sqlSelect = 'SELECT * FROM `Arduino`.`Condominos` WHERE RFID = ?;'; 
    con.query(sqlSelect, [value], function (err, result)
    {
        if (result.length == 0) //Confere se o select feito no BD retorna algum resultado
        {                
            cartaoSalvo = false; console.log('Status do cartão - Node: '+cartaoSalvo);
        }
        else
        {
            cartaoSalvo = true; console.log('Status do cartão - Node: '+cartaoSalvo);                                    
            port.write(cartaoSalvo.toString(), (err) => {
                if (err) {
                  return console.log('Erro no método write: ', err.message);
                }                
              });           
            const sqlInsert = 'INSERT INTO `Rfid` (`rfid`) VALUES (?);';
            con.query(sqlInsert, [value], function (err, result) {            
            if (err)
                console.error(err);
            });
        }

        if (err)
            console.error(err);                
    });      
}
```

Os módulos do Node podem ser aplicados com `npm install express serialport mysql socket.io`.

E o código do banco SQL:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `Arduino`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
  DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;

USE `Arduino`;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Rfid` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  `rfid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE = InnoDB 
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Condominos` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  `nome` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `rfid` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB 
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4
  DEFAULT COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;

  INSERT INTO `Condominos` (`nome`, `rfid`) VALUES ("Tony", "E3D2F71B");
  INSERT INTO `Condominos` (`nome`, `rfid`) VALUES ("Steve", "99AA1E63");
```

Espero que eu tenha sido claro em passar a minha situação.